# activity does not starts from the count down timer using intent

Tags: android

I am working on a simple game. In which after 30 seconds the game ends and the new activity i.e game over activity opens. But the gameOver activity is not opening. app keeps crashing.
here is my code of starting a new activity

```
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisuntilfinished, 1000) {
       @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            String valueTv = "" + (l / 1000) + "s";
            tvTimer.setText(valueTv);
        }


        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            btn0.setClickable(false);
            btn1.setClickable(false);
            btn2.setClickable(false);
            btn3.setClickable(false);
            Toast.makeText(startGames.this, "Game over", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
            //                startGameOver();
        Intent intent = new Intent(startGames.this, GameOver.class);
        intent.putExtra("points", points);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    }.start();
```

Can anybody help me to make my app running

stack trace :

```
2020-07-08 11:40:41.455 8118-8118/com.example.mathgame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mathgame, PID: 8118
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mathgame/com.example.mathgame.GameOver}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.mathgame.GameOver.onCreate(GameOver.java:15)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

2020-07-08 11:40:41.461 1742-2204/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.mathgame/.GameOver
2020-07-08 11:40:41.465 1742-2204/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.mathgame/.startGames
2020-07-08 11:40:41.470 1742-1779/system_process I/ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.example.mathgame u0

Comment: It would help if you shared the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: edited the quesiton and added the stack trace of the crash please see this

Comment: Edit your question with the XML file of the game over activity as well as GameOver.class file also

Comment: i just read the stack trace and find out the error. I have used one blank view. which causes object null reference error. I removed it and the activity starts working.

Comment: I am new at android studio. Thanks for the idea of stack trace.

Comment: You need to share file that's referenced where in GameOver.java you say:`setContentView(R.layout.some_file)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably `points` is an integer value and in `GameOver` activity you are trying to set that integer to TextView without converting it to String value.

Comment: Your stacktrace claims that ` Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`

 Your stacktrace shows that one of the strings is null that you are trying to compare equality with another string. For this case your app crashes. Investigate where you are trying to use `if(string1.equals(string2))`. At least one of the strings must be null.  Let me know if it works

Comment: Actually I was taken an empty view between two images to make them align. and didn't provide it any value. as it was empty I didn't notice it in the preview. That cause me this error. And now I removed the empty textview and used the gravity property to align them. Should i close this question

Comment: sure. I have done it but I have less than 15 reputation points

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to open a new activity after 30 second pass.So for this you can use Thread

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(i+"");
                            if(i==30)
                            {
                                Intent intent=new Intent(startGames.this, GameOver.class);
                                intent.putExtra("points",points);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    });


                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
```

To update your textview you need to use handler